# why does axios GET request get an http 415 response

Tags: http, axios, content-type

here is my code

```
    getItemsPurchasedToday() {
  const path = 'http://localhost:5000/items-today';
  axios.get(path, {
    params: { items_for: this.addItemForm.item_for },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      this.items = res.data.items;
      this.total = res.data.total;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(error);
    });
},
```

and I got a 415 response, I tried to set content-type header in the request, but it doesn't work